# Настройка iptables для работы по белому списку

Tags: iptables

Добрый день. Возможно, я обращаюсь не туда. Если так, прошу меня извинить.

**Мне нужно настроить iptables таким образом, чтобы запрещать доступ всем, а разрешать только некоторым, то есть настроить их работу "по белому списку".** Поскольку логика работы iptables для меня до сих пор не всегда понятна, я решил обратиться к тем, кто знает, как этим пользоваться.

Например, я могу вносить крайне простые запрещающие правила для айпи (iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j DROP), и я понимаю, как они работают, и они так и работают, но вот когда я пытался совместить полный запрет и открыть доступ некоторым, тут я не понимаю, как работают эти чёртовы таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

работают элементарно.

запрещающее «всё подряд» правило должно идти самым последним.

пример на «чистой» цепочке `INPUT` (`-A` — добавить в конец цепочки):

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -s 192.168.0.1 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

либо (`-I` — вставить в начало цепочки):

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -s 192.168.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

после выполнения либо первого, либо второго набора команд *icmp*-пакеты (в просторечии «пинги») будут «приходить» только с адреса `192.168.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я для работы с iptables пользуюсь инструментом Shorewall. Как его описывают сами разработчики "утилита для конфигурирования файерволла/шлюза в Linux". Более удобные и понятные настройки, проверка правил. В интернете найдете кучу описаний, рекомендаций и примеров.
[Официальный сайт](http://shorewall.net/) 
[Описание из библиотеки Баумана](http://ru.bmstu.wiki/Shorewall)
[Информация с Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/80271/)
множество дополнительной инфы найдете в интернете